# Operador test en un condicional

Tags: linux, script, ksh

Estoy empezando a hacer scripts sencillos en Linux, y tengo una duda al mandar parámetros a uno. El script es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/ksh 
if test $1 -lt $2
    then
            echo "La cadena 1 es menor que la cadena 2"
    else
            echo "Las cadenas son iguales"
    fi
```

La cuestión es que si le quito el `test` me sale un error de `not such file or directory`, y no estoy muy seguro de que poner `test` sea lo adecuado.

Comment: Con el `test` te funciona, sin el `test` no te funciona, ¿por qué piensas que no puede ser adecuado?

Comment: He eliminado la etiqueta [tag:c]. No veo en qué están relacionadas

Comment: No entiendo como funciona "test", y no soy muy entusiaste de usar cosas que no entiendo un minimo. Yo supongo que lo mas adecuado es comprobar que las variables que quiero comparar en el if son enteros antes de llegar al if. Tambien puede ser que exista una manera de enviar como parametro los valores siendo estos int, porque me imagino que los estoy enviando como cadena de caracter. Pero como digo, estoy empezando con esto y no se muy bien como funciona.

Comment: Nótese que ese `!/bin/ksh` no hace nada a menos que le pongas un shebang al principio --> `#!/bin/ksh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` es un comando y sirve para validar lo que viene a continuación. Normalmente se representa por su hermano sinónimo `[` que te permite cambiar la sintaxis a algo más claro visualmente:

```
if test expresión_booleana
```

Por

```
if [ expresión_booleana ]
```

O también (como muy bien indica el [manual](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/test.1.asp) o Alvaro en [su excelente respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/90378/83)):

```
if [[  expresión_booleana ]]
```

La idea, pues, es que los tres métodos reciben una expresión boleana que luego es evaluada para llegar al `then` o al `else`, etc. Por tanto, lo que deberías escribir es algo así como:

```
if [ "$1" -lt "$2" ]
```

Tienes más información en el [Bash Reference Manual → 4.1. Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)  (sí, estás en KSH pero la referencia es equivalente).

---

Respecto a por qué no funciona si quitas la palabra `test`, debes tener en cuenta que lo que resulta es:

```
if $1 -lt $2
```

que no es una expresión válida, pues `if` necesita ser expresado de la forma:

```
if test-commands; then
  consequent-commands;
[elif more-test-commands; then
  more-consequents;]
[else alternate-consequents;]
fi
```

Lo que realmente está haciendo es intentar ejecutar el comando:

```
tu_primer_parametro -lt tu_segundo_parametro
```

Por lo que busca el binario `tu_primer_parametro` en todos los directorios de `$PATH` como, lógicamente, no lo encuentra, dice que "not such file or directory".
Puedes reproducirlo diciendo:

```
touch /tmp/hola
if /tmp/hola -lt 2; then echo "fichero encontrado"; else echo "no encontrado"; fi
```

Aquí seguramente te dará un error de este tipo, pues `/tmp/hola` no será un fichero ejecutable:

> ```
> ksh: /tmp/hola: cannot execute [Permission denied]
> ```

---

Por otra parte, es recomendable acostumbrarse a usar comillas dobles a la hora de tratar los argumentos que recibas. De este modo evitarás problemas futuros al decir cosas como:

```
$ v="hola que tal"
$ if [ -z $v ]; then echo "vacio"; fi
bash: [: too many arguments
$ if [ -z "$v" ]; then echo "vacio"; fi
```

Es decir, en el primer caso se expande todo a algo que son demasiados argumentos para el operador `test`:

```
if [ -z hola que tal ]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, llevaba un rato buscando algo que me aclarara todo el asunto!

Answer (score 1):

En shell scripting, las expresiones que van dentro de una condición pueden ir de varias maneras diferentes:

1. **Precedidas por el operador `test`**. Es equivalente a la siguiente.
2. **Envueltas en corchetes simples `[`**. Es la comprobación booleana tradicional y está disponible en todos los shell POSIX.
3. **Envueltas en corchetes dobles `[[`**. Es una versión ampliada de las anteriores que funciona en bash, permite ejecutar comprobaciones más avanzadas, como por ejemplo expresiones regulares.
4. **Envueltas en paréntesis simples `(`**. Ejecuta la expresión en un subshell.
5. **Envueltas en paréntesis dobles `((`**. Se usa para expresiones aritméticas.
6. **Sin nada**. Simplemente se ejecuta el comando que vaya después y el `if` se hará dependiendo del resultado del comando.

En tu caso particular:

- Cuando tienes el `test` en la comparación, la expresión se procesa como una expresión lógica y se entrará en  el `if` si el parámetro 1 es menor o igual que el parámetro 2.
- Cuando quitas el `test`, lo que se hace es que se intenta ejecutar la expresión: se busca el ejecutable que coincia con el parámetro 1, y se le pasan los modificadores `-lt` y el parámetro 2 como parámetro. Como el parámetro 1 no coincide con ningún archivo o programa presente en el directorio, se muestra el error de que no se ha encontrado ese archivo a ejecutar.

---

Referencia:

- [Confused about operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/confused-about-operators-vs-vs-vs)
- [Single or double brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/single-or-double-brackets)
- [test, [, [[](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/test.1.asp)
- [ksh, difference between double bracket and single bracket](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/173690-ksh-difference-between-double-bracket-single-bracket.html)

Comment: En Bash sería cierto lo que comentas, pero el error _no such file or directory_ aparece en Ksh pese a que existe el fichero. Validación: `touch hola; if hola -lt 2; then echo "yes"; fi`

Comment: Tienes razón. ¿Puede ocurrir por lo que pones en el otro comentario de que no tiene bien puesto `#!/bin/ksh`?

Comment: Creo que no. Acabo de abrir una consola de Ksh y hacer pruebas y creo que encontré el problema: no puede encontrar el fichero "hola" porque no está en el $PATH. Si le pones la ruta completa sí funciona: `if /tmp/hola -lt 2; then echo "yes"; fi`, devolviendo un lógico `ksh: /tmp/hola: cannot execute [Permission denied]`.